# Growing chart value - chart.js

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

I want to do so the chart value increases itself by 1 each second. How can I achieve that? I tried setting a counter variable and then increasing it every second but it didn't work dynamically for some reason.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Crash line',
            data: [0, 1], //1 here needs to be increased so the graphs grows up
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(108, 170, 91, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [chart.js documention](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateduration-lazy) and [chart.js update documention](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html).
You need to use the chart.update method as so:

```
var options = //chart.js option object
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

var somefunc = function(chart){
var chartDatasetLength = chart.data.datasets[0].data.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < chartDatasetLength; i++){
    chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] += 1;
  }
  chart.update();
}

setInterval(somefunc, 1000, chart);
```

A working [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9h1ek4hv/).